# Using jsfiddle: how can I use underscore.js or backbone.js libraries?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, jsfiddle

In `jsfiddle` is possible to use for example jQuery.
But I cannot see any references, for example, to underscore or backbone.js.

If I run this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/J6Pq5/) I get the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined
```

How can I use underscore.js or backbone.js libraries in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add the URL for the required library under the "Add Resources" button on the left hand side.

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/BwHxv/

Answer (score 3):

I'm using a self-made jsfiddle base with log included in the HTML, so you don't have to open developer tools :

Includes Backbone and Underscore

http://jsfiddle.net/drinchev/NL2z9/2/

Answer (score 1):

I usually started out from this: http://jsfiddle.net/dandiebolt/auHFG/

This comes up as the first result when searching for "jsfiddle underscore".