# angularjs filter nested array-using-checkboxes-with-angularjs

Tags: angularjs, filter

I am following [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21058284/filter-array-using-checkboxes-with-angularjs) to filter nested json response. I have a nested property like this:

```
instances:{
     instance:[
     {cname:'name1', location:'pa', price:40, model:'2014' },     
     {cname:'name1', location:'ga', price:30 , model:'2014'},
     {cname:'name1', location:'ga', price:20, model:'2010' }        
    ]}
```

I can filter by top level properties using the above mentioned example but not the child properties.
I have modified above example to show nested properties of my json here.http://jsfiddle.net/jackAndy/qygL2m01/4/. I am new to angularjs.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31398614/how-to-group-and-display-the-values-in-angular-js/31399083#31399083 have a look at my answer to this question u can filter already filtered array in the view there is a codepen too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First of all - why You use `instances.instance`? It it not principally, use `players.instances = []`;
2. Use `Group` functions only 1 time after data loading; Watching filters - it's not necessary in this case;

Function for get filters values (I use `underscore` `uniq` function, You can use Your own algorithm for this):

```
$scope.getFieldsValues = function(field){
    var result = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.players.length; i++){
        result.push($scope.players[i][field]);
    }
    return _.uniq(result);
};
```

Filter for `players`:

```
$scope.testFl = function(el){
    for(var filter in $scope.filters){
        var filterArray = [];
        for(var i in $scope.filters[filter]){
            if($scope.filters[filter][i]) filterArray.push(i);
        }

        //You can make array with instances properties & compare with it;
        if(filter === 'location'){
            if(el.instances && el.instances.length > 0){
                var intersection = el.instances.filter(function(n) {
                    return filterArray.indexOf(n[filter]) != -1
                });
            } else if(filterArray.length > 0){return false;}
        } else {
            if(filterArray.length > 0 && filterArray.indexOf(el[filter]) === -1) return false;
        }

    }
    return true;
};
```

Template:

```
<li ng-repeat="player in players | filter:testFl" >
```

Filter for instances:

```
$scope.testFl2 = function(el){
    var filterArray = [];
    for(var i in $scope.filters.location){
        if($scope.filters.location[i]) filterArray.push(i);
    }
    return filterArray.length > 0 && filterArray.indexOf(el.location) === -1 ? false : true;
};
```

Template:

```
<span ng-repeat="loc in player.instances | filter:testFl2" >
```

[Fiddle for this;](http://jsfiddle.net/kv08h0q3/)

**UPDATE:**
Function for count:

```
$scope.getCount = function(field, value){
    var obj = {};
    obj[field] = value;
    return _.where($scope.players, obj).length;
};
```

[Update fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/onctqvm5/) - update underscore, add count function;

I hope this will help you;

For answer were used:
[Add underscore to jsfiddle;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10381066/using-jsfiddle-how-can-i-use-underscore-js-or-backbone-js-libraries)
[variable property name in `where` underscore.js;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21009572/how-to-use-a-variable-for-a-property-name-when-using-underscore-js-findwhere-fun)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I have instance inside instances and it is xml response from a web service. I cannot change web service. I am converting response to json using xml2json. This is xml structure that I am receiving:<Player> <Name>string</Name> <Shirt>string</Shirt> <Instances><Instance>Location>string</Location> </Instance><Instance><Location>string</Location></Instance></Instances></Player>

Comment: @Jacky sad, but not critical. Just change all `instances` ti `instances.instance` & add `xxx.instances &&` to check of existence; [jsfiddle update;](http://jsfiddle.net/jLw8m2e6/)

Comment: Good solution, marked it as solution.I am having a strange issue. When I  filter for single new instance of a location, It is showing all instances where location is null. For example, When I filter with "la" it is showing two extra results.[link](http://jsfiddle.net/jackAndy/jLw8m2e6/1/)

Comment: @Jacky OK. My English is not understood allow me to tell you the theoretical part. You must add `testFl2` to `testFl1` if `filter === 'location'`; [This code need refactoring](http://jsfiddle.net/6tnzzrc7/) but it working;